# Convert Python Code to Use Buttons instead

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter

I have tried but I am not sure how to make this code work using buttons instead of the canvas. Its for a calculator using tkinter. I need to make this work using Buttons but everything i have tried has failed. If someone could tell me how to do it or even do the whole thing that would be much appreciated. I am new to this language and its confusing me. Thanks

```
from Tkinter import *

def quit():
    window.destroy()

def buttonclick(event):
    global calcvalue
    global savedvalue
    global operator
    pressed = ""
    if event.x >10 and event.x <70 and event.y > 50 and event.y < 110 : pressed = 7
    if event.x >10 and event.x <70 and event.y > 120 and event.y < 180 : pressed = 4
    if event.x >10 and event.x <70 and event.y > 190 and event.y < 250 : pressed = 1
    if event.x >10 and event.x <70 and event.y > 260 and event.y < 320 : pressed = 0
    if event.x >80 and event.x <140 and event.y > 50 and event.y < 110 : pressed = 8
    if event.x >80 and event.x <140 and event.y > 120 and event.y < 180 : pressed = 5
    if event.x >80 and event.x <140 and event.y > 190 and event.y < 250 : pressed = 2
    if event.x >150 and event.x <210 and event.y > 50 and event.y < 110 : pressed = 9
    if event.x >150 and event.x <210 and event.y > 120 and event.y < 180 : pressed = 6
    if event.x >150 and event.x <210 and event.y > 190 and event.y < 250 : pressed = 3
    if event.x >80 and event.x <140 and event.y > 260 and event.y < 320 : pressed =   "equals"
    if event.x >150 and event.x <210 and event.y > 260 and event.y < 320 : pressed = "clear"
    if event.x >220 and event.x <280 and event.y > 50 and event.y < 110 : pressed = "divide"
    if event.x >220 and event.x <280 and event.y > 120 and event.y < 180 : pressed = "times"
    if event.x >220 and event.x <280 and event.y > 190 and event.y < 250 : pressed = "minus"
    if event.x >220 and event.x <280 and event.y > 260 and event.y < 320 : pressed = "plus"


    if pressed == 0 or pressed == 1 or pressed == 2 or pressed == 3 or pressed == 4 or  pressed == 5 or pressed == 6 or pressed == 7 or pressed == 8 or pressed == 9 :
        calcvalue = calcvalue * 10 + pressed


    if pressed == "divide" or pressed == "times" or pressed == "minus" or pressed == "plus" :
        operator = pressed
        savedvalue = calcvalue
        calcvalue = 0

    if pressed == "equals":
        if operator == "divide": calcvalue =  savedvalue /calcvalue
        if operator == "times": calcvalue =  savedvalue * calcvalue
        if operator == "minus": calcvalue =  savedvalue - calcvalue
        if operator == "plus": calcvalue =  savedvalue + calcvalue

    if pressed == "clear":
        calcvalue = 0

    displayupdate()
    canvas.update()

def displayupdate():
    canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 280, 40, fill="white", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(260, 25,  text=calcvalue,font="Times 20  bold",anchor=E)

def main():
    global window
    global tkinter
    global canvas
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Simple Calculator")
    Button(window, text="Quit",  width=5, command=quit).pack()
    canvas = Canvas(window, width= 290, height=330, bg = 'beige')
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", buttonclick)




#Add the numbers
    canvas.create_rectangle(10, 50, 50, 110, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(40, 80,  text="7",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(10, 120, 70, 180, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(40, 150,  text="4",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(10, 190, 70, 250, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(40, 220,  text="1",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(10, 260, 70, 320, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(40, 290,  text="0",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(80, 50, 140, 110, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(110, 80,  text="8",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(80, 120, 140, 180, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(110, 150,  text="5",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(80, 190, 140, 250, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(110, 220,  text="2",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(150, 50, 210, 110, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(180, 80,  text="9",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(150, 120, 210, 180, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(180, 150,  text="6",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(150, 190, 210, 250, fill="yellow", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(180, 220,  text="3",font="Times 30  bold")

#Add the operators
    canvas.create_rectangle(80, 260, 140, 320, fill="green", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(110, 290,  text="=",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(150, 260, 210, 320, fill="green", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(180, 290,  text="C",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(220, 50, 280, 110, fill="pink", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(250, 80,  text="/",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(220, 120, 280, 180, fill="pink", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(250, 150,  text="*",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(220, 190, 280, 250, fill="pink", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(250, 220,  text="-",font="Times 30  bold")

    canvas.create_rectangle(220, 260, 280, 320, fill="pink", outline="black")
    canvas.create_text(250, 290,  text="+",font="Times 30  bold")

#Setup the display
    canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 280, 40, fill="white", outline="black")
    global calcvalue
    calcvalue = 0
    displayupdate()

    canvas.pack()
    window.mainloop()







main()
```

Comment: Kindly correct the indentation first.

Comment: Wow, one hell of a brute fore! :)

Comment: Why do you insist on button while canvas is working perfectly?

Comment: @fyr0049 Because good code matters?!

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil, Okay, I accept. I am just wondering

Comment: "everything i have tried has failed" - what have you tried? You say you want to use buttons, and have tried to use buttons, but the code shows us a canvas. Are you having problems creating the buttons? Hooking the buttons up to functions? Having the functions do something?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say why you're having a problem using buttons, so I don't know what problem you're trying to solve. Certainly it's possible to create a grid of buttons, and certainly it's possible for buttons to call functions when clicked.

To me, the real challenge here is to write code that is compact, understandable, and easy to maintain. You want it to be easy to add new functions and/or new operators without having to rework the whole GUI.

Personally I would use an object-oriented approach, creating custom objects that represent numerals, functions and operators. Since you're using a non-OO approach, I recommend creating some helper functions to abstract out some of the details.

You have three types of buttons: numbers, operators ("+", "-", etc) and functions ("C", "="). I would create a pair of functions for each type: one function to create the button, and one function to respond to the button. Doing this avoids having a single monolithic function to handle all button presses.

I would also add a helper function to lay out the buttons, just to make it easier to visualize the final product in the code.

Let's start with the number buttons. We know that all the number button has to do is insert that number into the calculator. So, let's first write a function to do that. In this case I'll assume you have an entry widget to hold the value, since working with canvas text objects is cumbersome:

```
def do_number(n):
    global entry # the entry where we should insert the number
    entry.insert("end", n)
```

If we call this function with `do_number("3")`, it will insert "3" into the calculator. We can use this same function for all of the buttons, all we have to do is pass in what number to insert. You can create similar functions named `do_operator` and `do_function`, which take the label of the button and do the appropriate thing. You could just as well have a unique function for each button if you want.

To create the button, we want a little helper function that can tie a button to that function. This example uses `lambda`, but you can use `functools.partial`, or a function factory. `lambda` requires the fewest extra steps, so we'll go with that.

```
def number(number):
    global frame
    b = Button(frame, text=label, command=lambda: do_number(number))
    return b
```

When we call this function like `number("4")`, it will create a button with "4" as the label. It will also call the function `do_number` with the number "4" as an argument, so that it will insert the proper string. You can then create similar functions named "operator" and "function" to create buttons that act as operators and those that act as functions.

> Note 1: I'm generally against using global variables in this manner.
>   Generally speaking it better to pass in the containing frame rather
>   than rely on a global. In this specific case the use of the global
>   makes the code a bit more compact, as you'll see in another paragraph
>   or two. If we were building this calculator as class, we could use an
>   instance variable instead of a global.
>
> Note 2: declaring the variable as global here has no real effect. Globals
>   must only be declared when you want to modify the variable. However, I put
>   the global statement in to serve as a declaration that I intend for the
>   variable named `frame` to be global. This is purely a matter of personal
>   preference

So, now we can create buttons of each time, and have them call a function with a unique parameter. Now all that is left is to use `grid` to organize the buttons. Another helper function will make this easier:

```
def make_row(row, *buttons):
    for column,button in enumerate(buttons):
        button.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")
```

This helper function lets us pass in a list of buttons, and it will lay them out in a row. Now, combining this with our helper functions to create the buttons, we can create the GUI with something like this:

```
frame = Frame(window, bg="beige")
entry = Entry(frame, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="nsew")
make_row(1, number("7"),   number("8"),   number("9"), operator("/"))
make_row(2, number("4"),   number("5"),   number("6"), operator("*"))
make_row(3, number("1"),   number("2"),   number("3"), operator("-"))
make_row(4, number("0"), function("="), function("C"), operator("+"))
```

Notice how it's now possible to see the layout of the buttons in the code. If you want to add another column, add another row, or rearrange the existing buttons, it should be completely self-evident how to do that.

Now, of course, this isn't the only way to accomplish this. You can do all of this without helper functions, and just create a few hundred lines of code. By taking a little extra time to break the code down into logical chunks you can create code that is considerably easier to read and maintain.

Comment: `global` is meaningless if all you do is read the variable - `global` only affects _assignment_ semantics

Comment: @Eric: while you are correct, by including the global statement it serves as a sort of declaration. Without the global statement, one might wonder whether it's a bug or not that frame isn't defined before being used. I suppose the same could be accomplished via a comment, but people don't read comments as often as they read the code. I'll update my answer to mention that.